# discord.js "TypeError: fn is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I started getting this *"TypeError: fn is not a function"* after I added the if-else statement to the code

```js
module.exports = {
    name: `verify`,
    description: "Verification part of bot",
    execute (client, message, args){
        let { channel, content, member } = message
        let timeout;

        const verified = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Verified");
        const notverified = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Not Verified");
        const rolemember = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Member");

      if(message.member.roles.cache.some(notverified)){ 
        
       message.delete({timeout: 100})
        message.member.roles.remove(notverified)
        message.member.roles.add(verified) 
        message.member.roles.add(rolemember)
     
        message.channel.send(`${member}You have been successfully verified!`);


        message.channel.send(`Type to verify yourself!`);


       } else {
          message.delete({timeout: 100})
          message.channel.send("You have already been verified!");
          message.delete({timeout: 1000})
          message.member.roles.add(role).catch(console.error);

       }
      }
    };
```

Thats the code I have and
my error is

```
if (fn(val, key, this))
                ^

TypeError: fn is not a function
```

Thank you to anyone that is able to help me find a fix for this.

Comment: Can you add the complete error as it might show where the error originated from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because [`.some()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=some) accepts a callback function only but `notverified` is a Role or a falsy value.

Instead of `.some()`, you could use [`.has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=has) to check if the user has the `notverified` role:

```js
if(message.member.roles.cache.has(notverified.id)) {}
```

Comment: Correct but I had to do 
`if(message.member.roles.cache.has(notverified.id)) {}`

Comment: Ah, yes, I've just fixed that :)